# I just want to call some specific function in my Lua script. How to do that?

Tags: lua

I just want to call some specific function in my Lua script.

A simple script:

```
msg("hello")
function showamsgbox()
msg("123")
end
```

I just want to let my C app call `showamsgbox()` only but not to run `msg("hello")` beacuse it will show a msgbox when i load this script! So how to do that to keep this situation away?

PS:it is just example.sometimes i want to let users make thier own plugins in my program.but I do not want them write something outside the functions(i want to use functions to decide what to do.for example function OnLoad() means it will be run when i load it ).If there is something outside functions i cannot control them!

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The script defines two variables when run: `a` and `geta`. Recall that `function geta()...end` is the same as `geta=function()...end`.

Comment: geta will be defined in the globals table alongside a. You can retrieve the function and invoke it however many times you like.

Comment: @brianm, yes, but you cannot define `geta` *without* defining `a`. That was the original question.

Comment: thanks for your answer:).it is just example,i know that is wrong.sometimes i want to let users make thier own plugins in my program.but I do not want them write something outside the functions(i want to use functions to decide what to do.for example function OnLoad() means it will be run when i load it ).If there is something outside functions i cannot control them!

Comment: @user1256804: There's really nothing you can do. It's a Lua script; those functions don't exist until you execute it, at which point the script does whatever it wants. If you want to sandbox your scripts, so that they can't do something to the system, then you can do that by not installing all of the Lua standard libraries. Or just strategically removing certain functions. But ultimately, you can't control what a Lua script does. The most you could do is run it through a simple parser that only keeps the function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The a = 9 will be called when the script is initially evaluated in a lua_State.

If you reuse that lua_State instance, you can retrieve the function and invoke it without re-initializing a.

Comment: thanks for your answer:).it is just example.sometimes i want to let users make thier own plugins in my program.but I do not want them write something outside the functions(i want to use functions to decide what to do.for example function OnLoad() means it will be run when i load it ).If there is something outside functions i cannot control them!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to sandbox scripts. Just give them a suitable, separate environment before running them. It may be an empty one or it may contain references to the functions you want them to use. They can write at will in their environment and it will not affect yours. Then just get the value of `OnLoad` or whatever user function you want to call and call it.